# Do I need to nest observation windows in each trial as a random effect?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, random-effects-model

The study is as follows:

- Participants are observed at three ages.
- Observations at each age involves 10 trials (i.e., stimuli they are presented with while their eye gaze is measured).
- Each trial is split into 3 time windows.

Would it be correct to use a nested random effects structure, with windows nested within trials, trials nested within age, and age nested within participants?

Answer (score 3):

Very often the correlation structure in the data is simpler than the one the design of the study suggests. Hence, I would suggest that you start with a simple random intercept term per participant, include then a random slope for age, and then a nested random effect for trials. At each step, you can use likelihood ratio tests to see if the additional random effects improve the model.